# Remove Table Column from an Ant task - OpenJpa

Tags: java, ant, openjpa

It is said that with the use of org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.ant.MappingToolTask it is possible to synchronize domain models classes with db schema. So by having following script as an Ant task i was able to add new columns to the given databases on the persistance.xml.

```
<target>
   <taskdef name="mappingtool" classpathref="maven.compile.classpath" classname="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.ant.MappingToolTask" />
      <mappingtool schemaAction="refresh" >
      </mappingtool>
</target>
```

This script adds new columns every time i add a new attribute to the domain class. but it wont remove the corresponding column if i remove them from the domain class. Is there anyway to archive the synchronization for both (add/remove) with an single ant script?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look through the user manual [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_mapping_mappingtool) and [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_schema_schematool).

- **refresh**: Equivalent to retain, then add.

  - **retain**: Keep all schema components in the given XML definition, but drop the rest from the database. This action never adds any schema components.
  - **add**: This is the default action if you do not specify one. It brings the schema up-to-date with the given XML document by adding tables, columns, indexes, etc. This action never drops any schema components.

Perhaps try changing "**refresh**" to "**drop,add**".